# Type Error: is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, django, session

I`m trying to pass database objects from one view to another view. But when I try to achieve this using SESSION, I am getting this "**is not JSON serializiable**" error.

My **Views.py**:

```
def index(request):
    listset = TheaterBase.objects.all()
    request.session['s_listset'] = listset

def otherview(request):
    result = request.session.get('s_listset')
```

How to pass the **Database** objects in between the views?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to? Why can't you do the query in the other view?

Comment: I need to use same query on all the views,
So I need to store them in the session, so that it reduce the Load of the Server. @DanielRoseman

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a very good reason. If you do this it will never update when new items are added; and the queryset will be stored separately for every single user. If you need to share a query, use a common function called by each view, or a context processor.

Answer (score 1):

Server sessions can store JSON objects only. You are trying to store a complex Django `QuerySet` object, which naturally is not JSON serializable.

And trust me, even if it was, you wouldn't want to do this. It's not healthy to abuse your server's session with a high amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

Let's just assume that your TheaterBase class is something like below(pseudo code)

```
class TheaterBase:
  field1 ...
  fielld2 ...
 -------
 # a method to produce json serializable representation 
 def as_dict(self):
   return {'field1': self.field1, 'fileld2': self.fielld2}
```

Then on you view do

```
listset = [x.as_dict() for x in TheaterBase.objects.all()]
```

The issue here is the object coming out of your db query are not json serializable. The as_dict method above is constructing a json serializable representation of that object.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using django serializers

```
from django.core import serializers
listset = serializers.serialize("json", TheaterBase.objects.all())
```

Comment: Thanks but `listset = serializers.serialize("json", TheaterBase.objects.all().values_list('field')) is not working
`